# Please help me identify this cassette

Tags: cassette

[image]

I recently found this cassette that appears to have only 5 speeds. No locking or anything. Is it incomplete? Can it still be used with a normal freehub (with spacers of course)?

Thank you!

Comment: Megarange were typically 14-34. Its possible someone fitted a 6 speed to a 5speed hub and left of the 14tooth cog.

Comment: The dirt marks show there has been a sixth cog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an incomplete 7-speed 11-34 Shimano CS-HG50, the model name is written on lockring. I think you can use it with spacers/lockring or source missing parts from another 7 speed cassette. 
[image]

Comment: I've also seen similar (perhaps off-brand) units as a 6.